# CRM 2015 - Loading business logic

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2015

We recently upgraded to the CRM 2015 U1 update to our CRM Online instance. However, we have a few forms that when you try and load them, you get a never-ending "Loading business logic..."

When we turn on Legacy Form Loading in the settings, the forms load just fine without any errors. When we turn the Legacy Form Loading back off, we get the endless loading once again. I haven't been able to find anything from Microsoft about this. Ideas?

Comment: Did you try to disable all the script on the form? The loading process of the Turbo forms is asynchronous, against the synchronous load of the old forms, it's possible that something is going wrong during the javascript loading.

Comment: When you open form, press F12 key and then Ctrl+3, once you are in debugger mode you will be able to see errors thrown in your JS files.